# How can I add total rows to my groupby aggregation in python?

Tags: pandas, group-by

I currently have a dataframe with survey data. Each row is an individual and I have 4 categorical columns ['AGE_GROUP','STATE','MONTH', 'SEX'] and I have multiple indicator variables to identify if an individual is employed, unemployed, etc, Finally, I have a weight variable that indicates how many a single individual represents in the general population.

I group the data by the 4 categorical variables and compute estimates for each of them using user defined functions. But, I also want to have the total for each grouping variables.

These are the user defined functions.

```
result = grouped_data.apply(lambda x: pd.Series({
    'Population': agg.weighted_frequency(x['POP'], x['FINALWT']),
    'LabourForce': agg.weighted_frequency(x['LABOURFORCE'], x['FINALWT']),
    'Employed': agg.weighted_frequency(x['EMPLOYED'], x['FINALWT']),
    'Employed_ft': agg.weighted_frequency(x['EMPLOYED_FT'], x['FINALWT']),
    'Employed_pt': agg.weighted_frequency(x['EMPLOYED_PT'], x['FINALWT']),
    'Unemployed': agg.weighted_frequency(x['UNEMPLOYED'], x['FINALWT']),
    'Unemployment_rate': agg.unemployment_rate(x['UNEMPLOYED'], x['LABOURFORCE'], x['FINALWT']),
    'Participation_rate': agg.participation_rate(x['LABOURFORCE'], x['FINALWT']),
    'Employment_rate': agg.employment_rate(x['EMPLOYED'], x['LABOURFORCE'], x['FINALWT'])
}))

result = result.reset_index()
```

Is there a way I could add a rows total?

The current result dataframe would look something like this :
[image]

Comment: Can you provide expected answer sample.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, and assuming your columns contain 0/1 or False/True and you want to weight this with FINALWT, you need to multiply and sum:

```
{
# ...
'Employed_total': x['EMPLOYED'].mul(x['FINALWT']).sum(),
# ...
}
```

Which can be simplified to a dot product:

```
{
# ...
'Employed_total': x['EMPLOYED'] @ x['FINALWT'],
# ...
}
```

Or, maybe you just want a total weight?

```
{
# ...
'Total': x['FINALWT'].sum(),
# ...
}
```

Comment: The function I pass to the .apply isn't the issue currently. The issue is how can I get to compute the values for those subtotal groups.